# Derive standard error of a transformed variable in linear regression

Tags: r, linear-regression, standard-error

I would like to calculate the standard error of a transformed variable from my linear regression, i.e. divide two variables and get the standard error from this variable.

I use the `deltamethod` function from the `msm` package, but fail to get accurate standard errors.

For example:

## Simulation of data:

```
set.seed(123)
nobs = 1000
data <- data.table(
  x1 = rnorm(nobs),
  x2 = rnorm(nobs),
  x3 = rnorm(nobs),
  x4 = rnorm(nobs),
  y = rnorm(nobs))
```

## Linear regression:

```
reg2 <- lm(y~x1+x2+x3+x4, data=data)
```

## Get the coef and vcov (Here I need to get rid of the missings, as some coefficients in my real data are NA and I calculate a lot of regressions in loop)

```
vcov_reg <- vcov(reg2)

coef_reg <- coef(reg2)
coef_reg <- na.omit(coef_reg) 
coef_reg <- as.numeric(coef_reg)
```

## Deltamethod, for the the variable x1 divided by x3 (meaning I should use x2 and x4 according to the msm package):

```
deltamethod(~ x2/x4, coef_reg, vcov_reg)
```

This gives me a standard error of the transformed variable (x1/x3) of 3.21, while all standard errors from this regression are around 0.03.

Any idea's why/what's wrong here?
Other suggestions to calculate it are also welcome.

Comment: And what do you think the answer is supposed to be?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the result.  In your example your data is centered at 0 so it shouldn't be too surprising that when dividing by the data that you end up with a large variance / standard error.

Note that your estimated coefficient for x3 is -0.017408626 so with a standard error of about 0.03 the CI for this coefficient crosses 0.  And that's the thing we're dividing by.  Hopefully that gives you some intuition for why the standard error seems to explode.  For some evidence that this really is part of the issue consider x1/x2 instead.

```
> deltamethod(~ x2/x3, coef_reg, vcov_reg)
[1] 0.3752063
```

Which is much smaller since the estimated coefficient for the denominator is bigger in this case (0.09)

But really there is nothing wrong with your code. It was just your intuition was wrong.  Alternative methods to estimate what you want would be to bootstrap or to use a Bayesian regression and look at the posterior distribution of the transformation.